# HttpComponentsClientHttpRequestFactory spring-web 5.3.12 does not support org.apache.hc.client5.http.classic.HttpClient

Tags: spring-boot, ehcache, apache-httpcomponents, ehcache-3, clientcache

Hoping for a solution. Just ran into this and what a snowball. ehCache3 and HttpClient Cache 5.1.1 are compatible. Not so for a any permutation of previous and current versions.

Now upgrading to Spring-Boot 2.5.6 i find that HttpComponentsClientHttpRequestFactory is not compatible with the latest setup of ehCache and HttpClient. RestTemplate cannot be initiated with the ehCache configured HttpClient. There goes the Client-Cache solution.

The search continues.....

Any input much appreciated!

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.